# Re-using conditional formatting in MS Office (Word/Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

I very often find myself with a formatting that I want to apply to several specific but isolated parts of a document or worksheet, without disturbing the format of the surrounding areas.

The ideal solution would be to select the text/cell with the desired formatting, click `Format Painter` and then go on a select-highlighting spree until I "turn-off" the `Format Painter` option. Does such a functionality exist in Word/Excel/both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality to copy formatting from a selection to more than one place exists in Word, you simply need to double click the **Format Painter** button in order to apply formatting to multiple locations.

For Excel I know that the format painter exists, hopefully double clicking works there as well.